# SpriteKit : calculate distance between two texture masks

Tags: sprite-kit, distance, skspritenode

I have two irregular shapes in SpriteKit, and I want to calculate the vertical distance from the base of a space ship and the (irregular) terrain right below.

Is there a way to do it ?
Thanks !
[image]

Comment: You can calculate the distance if the terrain is a filled polygon.

Answer (score 2):

Place an SKPhysicsBody that is in a shape of a line at the center of your ship  with a width of 1 and the height of your scene, then in the didBeginContact method,  grab the 2 contact points.  You now know 2 points, just use the distance formula  (in this case it is just y2-y1) and you have your answer

Comment: This cannot work, there are more than 2 points involved during the contacts, are you agree? Or did you think about a different way? Could you explain better your idea?

Comment: There can only be 2. The bottom of the ship in the first contact, and the the ground in the second contact.  Since we only need the bottom of the ship once, we could optimize it further by moving the line to the point of contact of the ship, thereby future updates would only need to do 1 contact check (the ground)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon But if you put a line with a height of a scene, isn't that dBC will be called multiple times? It is possible. So how to differentiate which point is ship's bottom point? Same goes for ground.

Comment: You are starting at the center of the ship and making your way to the ground,  the line is the scene height to handle all variation, differentiating should be trivial, check the node or categoryBitmask

Comment: If you are worried in case of the body being a full body and the contact is grabbing every point from center to bottom of the ship, then the answer is the point at the lowest y,  and the ground is opposite, the point at the highest y

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Could work like that I guess. I was thinking that you are talking about the line accross the whole scene vertically :)

Comment: It does not work, because the rectangular SKPhysicsBody is rigid, and my ship cannot move down (in fact, it oscillates at the top of the rectangle like a flower on its stem !

Comment: What do you mean it does not work?  Neither of what you said has any bearing on my answer

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: I tried to make what you said, adding this rectangular SKPhysicsBody, and of course this contact between the rectangle and the ground is detected, but as the rectangle is a physical body, it blocks the ship... Maybe I didn't understand, cause I made the rectangle a child of the ship. But if I don't, and then move the ship to the left or to the right, the rectangle does not follow...

Comment: why would it block anything?  make sure that you only are using collision bit  for the objects you want to do collision on

Comment: Like this ?
SKShapeNode *radar = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithRectOfSize:CGSizeMake(1, 10000)];
    radar.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(1, 10000)];
    radar.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = radarCategory;
    radar.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = groundCategory;
    radar.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = groundCategory;
    [self addChild:radar]; // self is the ship.

Comment: Whatever I do with your solution, it does not work. I get a single contact, and I want the distance to be calculated continuously. And if I should re-create a new rectangular SKPhysicsBody at each update, it appears to be a waste of resources.

Comment: You do not need to create a new body every time, you only create it once and you attach it when you need to measure and remove when you are done

Comment: Hell now that I am thinking about it,  Add a SKPhysicsBody to an independent SKNode, at the beginning of your update add the node to the scene where your ship is, on `didFinishUpdate` remove it from the scene.  You now have a continuous check going.

Comment: Hi KnightOfDragon. After hours of trials, I get some strange behaviors from SpriteKit. If I use your method, I get the correct value but surrounded by a lot of "false positives", contacts at wrong position. If I let the rect SKPhysicsBody inserted in scene (but invisible) I get correct values, but only from time to time (at insufficient rate). Still trying to get it work.

Comment: When I get time, I will write up a sample project for you

Answer (score 0):

I found a different way to solve my problem, but I think that KnightOfDragon's one is conceptually better (although I did not manage to make it work).

The terrain's texture is essentially a bitmap with opaque and transparent pixels. So I decided to parse these pixels, storing the highest opaque pixel for each column, building a "radar altitude map". So I just have to calculate the difference between the bottom of the ship and the altitude of the column right beneath its center:

```
CFDataRef imageData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(terrain.texture.CGImage));
const UInt32 *pixels = (const UInt32*)CFDataGetBytePtr(imageData);

NSMutableArray *radar = [NSMutableArray new];
for (long col = 0; col < terrain.size.width; col++)
    [radar addObject:@(0)];

for (long ind = 0; ind < (terrain.size.height * terrain.size.width); ind++)
{
    if (pixels[ind] & 0xff000000) // non-transparent pixel
    {
        long line = ind/terrain.size.width;
        long col = ind - (line*terrain.size.width);
        if ([radar[col]integerValue] <terrain.size.height-line) radar[col] = @(terrain.size.height-line);
    }
}
```

This solution could be optimized, of course. It's just the basic idea.

I've added an image to show the original texture, its representation as opaque/transparent pixels, and a test by putting little white nodes to check where the "surface" was.
[image]